# Javascript/Jquery onClick using HTML Div not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

When I click on my "php1" div it doesn't do anything.

The location.reload() is a placeholder, just an easy way of knowing whether or not the onClick works.

```htm
    <div class="php-task">
      <h1>PHP</h1>
      <div id="php1" class="text">
        <p>Display/setvars</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```js
    $("#php1").click(function (e) { 
      e.preventDefault();
    
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/pagehandler.php",
        data: {page: "task",task: 1},
        success: function (response) {
          location.reload();
        }
      }); 
    });
```

Comment: add `error` function to your ajax call to get actual error message

Comment: this doesn't make much sense to me: you are reloading on success (ajax is to avoid reloading) and you do nothing with the response?

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify({page: "task",task: 1})`

Comment: How many `<div id="php1" class="text">` does your page have?

Comment: `error: function( jqXHR,  textStatus,  errorThrown )` Also have a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: @mbharanidharan88 Javascript does not have types, so in JS it's `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)`

Comment: Alright maybe some extra information helps.
When clicking the Div it doesn't do anything, a simple console.log() right below the e.preventdefault(); doesn't give me anything.

Comment: @connexo, Yes I agree, Just copy pasted

Comment: If possible, try to post `pagehandler.php` code also

Comment: Try to attach the click to the class `text` instead like `$(".text").click(function (e) {`

Comment: @connexo A couple but they all have id's going up so php1,php2,php3....

Comment: Have you tried `$(".text").click(function (e) {` ?!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code? Might be your HTML is dynamically loaded after page load.

```
$(function(){

    $('body').on('click', '#php1', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/pagehandler.php",
        data: {page: "task",task: 1},
        success: function (response) {
          location.reload();
        }
      }); 

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to show you that it won't work for duplicate id elements (and that it **does** work as a reduced example for the first div with that `id`, which **must be unique**):

```js
$("#php1").click(function (e) { 
  console.log('clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="php-task">
  <h1>PHP</h1>
  <div id="php1" class="text"><!-- clicking this will trigger the handler -->
    <p>Display/setvars</p>
    <p>clicking this will trigger the handler</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="php-task">
  <h1>PHP</h1>
  <div id="php1" class="text"><!-- clicking this will NOT trigger the handler -->
    <p>Display/setvars</p>
    <p>clicking this will NOT trigger the handler</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case with multiple divs `php1,php2,php3...` it will be better to attach the click event using classes instead :

```js
$(function() {
  $(".php-task .text").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log('Task with id : ' + this.id + ' clicked.');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="php-task">
  <h1>PHP</h1>
  <div id="php1" class="text">
    <p>Display/setvars</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="php-task">
  <h1>PHP</h1>
  <div id="php2" class="text">
    <p>Display/setvars</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="php-task">
  <h1>PHP</h1>
  <div id="php3" class="text">
    <p>Display/setvars</p>
  </div>
</div><br><br><br>
```

Comment: EyesReye If you're going to attach the event to the other divs you may have to take a look to this suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#task").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/pagehandler.php",
            data: {
                page: "task"
            },
            success: function (response) {
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Adding the following did the trick:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
```